# Get all subclasses defined in several python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, subclass

I got 2 python files implement test repository factory pattern:

### testrepository.py

```
class TestRepository(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def generate(self, username, password):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass

class RepositoryFactory(object):
    factories = {}

    def add_repo(identification, repo_factory):
        RepositoryFactory.factories[identification] = repo_factory
    add_repo = staticmethod(add_repo)

    def create_repo(identification, server, dirpath, reponame):
        if identification not in RepositoryFactory.factories:
            RepositoryFactory.factories[identification] = \
                eval(identification + '.Factory()')
        return RepositoryFactory.factories[identification].create(server, dirpath, reponame)
    create_repo = staticmethod(create_repo)
```

### gitrepository.py

```
from testrepository import TestRepository, RepositoryFactory

class GitRepository(TestRepository):
    def __init__(self, server, dirpath, reponame):
        super(GitRepository, self).__init__()
        self.server = server
        self.dirpath = dirpath
        self.reponame = reponame
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
        self.fullPath = path.join(self.dirpath, self.reponame)

    def generate(self, username, password):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass

    class Factory(object):
        @staticmethod
        def create(server, dirpath, reponame):
            return GitRepository(server=server, dirpath=dirpath, reponame=reponame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    repo_type = TestRepository.__subclasses__().pop().__name__
    repo = RepositoryFactory.create_repo(repo_type,
                                         server='localhost',
                                         dirpath='/home/user/git',
                                         reponame='repo')
    repo.generate(username='test', password='test')
    repo.update()
```

Problem is ***repo_type = TestRepository.__subclasses__()*** in example above is empty, if I put all classes in one file it works:

```
>>> print TestRepository.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.GitRepository'>]
```

so question is how to fetch all subclasses from several python modules?

Comment: Why would you scan all subclasses? It could include all kinds of things not directly usable, e.g. under-defined abstract subclasses, test subclasses, etc. Instead I'd have each interested (sub)class register in a central registry (e.g. in the module initialization part run at import time), and your code to just scan that registry.

Comment: There are better options than using `eval` in `create_repo`, the best one (IMO) being to pass a reference to the function to call rather than a partial function name.

Comment: The idea behind all is use in code TestRepository (and not mention anywhere GitRepository), if so later on I can easily switch to any other kind of repository. So I need load TestRepository implementation (GitRepository) dynamically.

Comment: @chepner can you be more specific

Comment: If you want to call a function `FooRepository`, pass `FooRepository` as an argument and just call it; don't pass `"Foo"`.